# Firestore rules: maximum of 1000 expressions to evaluate has been reached

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I added a new functionality to my application and now I'm getting this error:

> maximum of 1000 expressions to evaluate has been reached

raised by firestore rules.

Because of it seems there are much less 1000 controls to be done for that specific write, I would like to ask some suggestions to avoid this behaviour or to introduce some vulnerabilities.

- are logical expressions short-circuited?
- what is defined as expression?
- will this limit be extended?

Do you have any advice to avoid this problem?

Comment: Post your Firestore security rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logical expression are short circuited.

An expression is anything that evaluates to some value.  For example, `true` is one expression.  `false || false` is three expressions.

There is no roadmap to change the limit. The limit is in place in order to prevent excessive resources being used by every operation.  Bear in mind also that security rules are free (except for document access), and there is always going to be strict limits on what is provided for free.

Since we can't see your rules, it's not really possible to recommend exact advice.  You should consider using functions to cut down on the number of expressions evaluated for some access.  If you find yourself typing things like `request.resource.data.foo` a lot, consider using a function and pass `request.resource.data` to it to extract values rather than evaluating `request.resource.data` repeatedly, which is three expressions.

Comment: Thanks Doug. So to have this clearer: true || false corresponds to how many expressions?
Because of it is a production application, I can't show my rules, but I can try to apply your suggestion to better access the resource data. Currently I'm calling newData() (which performs a request.resource.data) many times. I suppose a lot of devs is doing this so a blog post could definitely help! (if it's not already there)

Comment: The expression count is evaluated a runtime, not statically.  `true || false` will be one expression, because it's short-circuited.  The Firebase team is working on better documentation and video tutorials for security rules, so stay tuned for that.

Comment: @DougStevenson does the execution of a function also count toward the expression count? In other words does this count as three expressions or four when executed?

`function check() {
  return false || false
}`

Comment: @BrianNeisler A function call is one expression, not including the other things it does.

Comment: `Bear in mind also that security rules are free...there is always going to be strict limits on what is provided for free.` I am concerned that this stance, when applied to security rules, may drive developers away from this otherwise excellent product. I ran into this expression limit myself (I do use functions) and tech support's suggested workaround was to handle data validation on the client side. In my mind, there should be a much higher limit on security rule expressions given that server-side data validation is considered to be a best practice. Also, rules are not a free vs paid issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson `A function call is one expression, not including the other things it does` So how does creating a function for `request.resource.data` reduce the amount of expressions? As I understand it, it would just make the problem worse because if you call a function `getData() { return request.resource.data; }` that'll result in one expression for the call, plus three to get `request.resource.data`.

Comment: @ItsaMeTuni You can only create variables in functions, so I'm assuming he's suggesting that you extract your validation out of the top-level statement (`allow write: if request.resource.data...`) into a function where you can then save it as a variable like `function validate() { let data = request.resource.data; return data.something && data.somethingElse; }`.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson can you add an example please to your statement: "extract values rather than evaluating request.resource.data repeatedly". Possibly improve the solution? Thank you, it would really help to reduce conditions!