# Expressions in firebase firestore security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The usage and limit ([quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)) section of firebase clearly says that the firebase firestore security rule will allow only an `expression` with a maximum length of `1000` per request.But it does n't mentioning anything about the expressions.Can somebody explain about

1)What is an expression ?

2)How expression are evaluated ?

3)What are the possible way to reduce the length of evaluating expression ?

Answer (score 2):

Good question on an undocumented subject. My understanding is the following:

1) Anything that is evaluated

2) Example:

```
match /somepath {
  allow update: if request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.counter + 1
}
```

Here you have 10 expressions

- request.resource.data.counter => 4
- resource.data.counter => 3
- 1 => 1
- == and + => 1 each = 2

3) Calculate only once...

Example:

```
match /somepath {
  allow update: if request.resource.data.notchange1 == resource.data.notchange1  => 8 expressions
    && request.resource.data.notchange2 == resource.data.notchange2              => 8
    && request.resource.data.test1 > 0                                           => 6
    && request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time                           => 7
    && request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.counter + 1;               => 10
  }
 => 39 expressions in total
```

Better version:

```
match /somepath {
  allow update: if checkupdate();  => 1
  function checkupdate() {
    let mapafter = request.resource.data;         => 3
    let map = request.resource;                   => 2
    return mapafter.notchange1 == map.notchange1  => 5
      && mapafter.notchange2 == map.notchange2    => 5
      && mapafter.test1 > 0                       => 4
      && mapafter.timestamp == request.time       => 5
      && mapafter.counter == map.counter + 1;     => 7
  }
 => 32 expressions in total
```

Comment: So,let's say  if there are two update statement in my security rule, will both consider under one request evaluation ?

Comment: Did you know that firebase support is referencing this solutions as the expression count algorithm ? A paid product....disappointing!

Comment: @l1b3rty  what about cases with ternary operators? or multiple dimension ternary operators? I know everything is short circuited as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651525/firestore-rules-maximum-of-1000-expressions-to-evaluate-has-been-reached

Comment: @Dev, if both are evaluated under the same request then number of expressions is the sum of both

Comment: @Xao, what is evaluated count as expressions (a ? b : c) => 3 expressions I guess