# Firestore security rules limit of 1000 evaluations per request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I recently run into this limit. After some optimisations I was able to get within the limit but now I've got several questions.

1. Is that true that the number of expressions for the particular request is constant, i.e. it doesn't depend on the data involved?

For example if I use `[...].hasAny([...])` - is that always 1/constant expressions  or does it depend on the size of the lists involved?

What I'm trying to figure out is in regard to 1000 expressions, if any particular rule successfully executes in unit tests, is it safe to assume that the same rule will never hit this limit of 1000 in production or that would also depend on user data?

2. Is that true that the evaluation of expressions always take into account all possible routes and the number of expressions doesn't depend on the result of any conditions.

Example: consider the following rule

```
allow read, write: if condition1 || condition2 && condition3
```

In this case this will always be counted as 3 expressions (or is it?) despite if `condition1` was true or false

3. I guess there is no easy way to know the current level of expression evaluations for a specific request?
4. is there any documentation available on how this process of expression evaluation works in more detail?

Comment: figured that for (2) the answer is "no" - the evaluation count is calculated dynamically at runtime, so it would be different depending on the input data.

Answer (score 1):

The number of expressions in a rule depends on the data involved as it is equal to the number of expressions actually evaluated.
Your could have a rules with 10000 expressions but if all evaluation paths are under 500 expressions each then you are fine.

Regarding your two example:

1. `somevariable.hasAny(["a","b", "c", "d"])`: this is 7 expressions to me, `somevariable`, `hasAny` and one for each element of the list + 1 for the list itself. To test this you could write a rule calling a function with such a test, put 20 elements in the list and call the function many times until you hit the 1000 mark
2. `allow read, write: if condition1 || condition2 && condition3`. This may evaluate as 1 (if `condition1` is true), 2 (if `condition1` and `condition2` are false) or 3 (if `condition1` is false and `condition12` is true) expressions
3. Unfortunatly not, you only know when you have hit the 1000 mark
4. No official doc, just hints of firebaser here on SO for instance :(

Here are also two previous answers that may help: [Expressions in firebase firestore security rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744782/expressions-in-firebase-firestore-security-rule/61745946#comment135711496_61745946) and [Firestore rules: maximum of 1000 expressions to evaluate has been reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651525/firestore-rules-maximum-of-1000-expressions-to-evaluate-has-been-reached).

Comment: Thanks. yep, figured that it evaluates the number of expression at runtime (saw Doug's comment from firebase somewhere on SO on this). In that case I would though expect count for operations involving lists to be a function of the size of that list as I'd imaging internally it would iterate through the list and "evaluate" each expression. Ie. somevariable.hasAny(["a","b", "c", "d"]) would be `somevariable` + `hasAny` + `up to '4' times 'lengthOf(somevariable)' of '==' operations`. I guess there is no way to know that for sure?

Comment: Actually, thinking about this a bit more, I think you are right. A list lead to lengthOf(list) + 1 (plus one for the list itself). So annoying not to have this properly documented.

Comment: True, that's annoying. Still feels like lists are gonna be N x M. For example `["a", "b", "c", "d"].hasAny(["e", "f", "g", "h", "d"])` - normally this would require 4x5=20  comparisions for "==". And probably +1 for `hasAny`. If that's true, this can scale pretty quickly, hence lists should be controlled and should not be user generated. So if true, a single line like `[...10 elements...].hasAny[..100 elements..]` would be 1001 expressions and it would reject - I'll run this test when I get back to the security rules in my app. Unless you have a sandbox handy.

Comment: Just completed testing the lists - posted it as a separate answer. In short, my findings shows that complexity there is linear, ie `length(list1)` + `length(list2)` + 3 and it doesn't depend on the values of the elements of the lists. In the case of the example above it would be 12 expressions. After all, it's not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Figured for `[...].hasAny([...])`

1. complexity here is linear and is calculated like this:

`length(list1)` + `length(list2)` + `3` (1 for `list1` result, 1 for `list2` result and one for `hasAny`)

Example: `[1, 2, 3, 4].hasAny([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])` => 12 expressions (4 + 5 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 12)

2. The number of expressions doesn't depend on the values of the elements of the lists.

I.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4].hasAny([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])` and `[4, 4, 4, 4].hasAny([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])` both give 12 expressions, even though in the second case it's enough to have just one comparison to evaluate the whole expression to `true` (plus 3 more expressions as mentioned above).

I guess this has to do with the linear algorithm used internally for this.

**Note on the underlying tests:**

My tests involved hardcoded list like `[..10..].hasAny[...1000...]` that I first generated in javascript and outputted it in console. Then manipulated the list in playground to account for different scenarios.

I was using the following playground snippet:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {


        match /{document=**}/mycollection/{docId} {
          allow read: if hugeListRule();
        }

//====== helper functions start ==========

    function hugeListRule(){
       return [...10...].hasAny([...1000...])
    }
    
}
```

Playground url (change project_id to yours):

[https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{project_id}/firestore/rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/%7Bproject_id%7D/firestore/rules)

Comment: Awesome work, I wish this would be documented!